# Ruby on Rails 4: Pluck results to hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I turn:

```
Person.all.pluck(:id, :name)
```

to

```
[{id: 1, name: 'joe'}, {id: 2, name: 'martin'}]
```

without having to .map every value (since when I add or remove from the .pluck I have to do he same with the .map)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could simply do this

```
Person.select(:id,:name).as_json
```

You could try this as well

```
Person.all.as_json(only: [:id, :name])
```

Comment: Person.select(:id,:name).as_json is the shortest and you only have to change the field in one place
Can you add a way to work with aggregation functions like Person.all.as_json(only: ['sum(some_field)'])?

Comment: @LucasSteffen You can achieve the aggregation by defining a method and calling it. For example you can define as method name `sum_of_fields` in `Person` model which would return the sum of desired fields. Then you call that method as `Person.all.as_json(methods: [:sum_of_fields])`. For more details you could read this [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

Comment: The two possibilities provided are not identical, as the first one adds the id into the hash even if it is not asked for e.g. Person.select(:name).as_json returns  ```[{id: nil, name: 'joe'}, {id: nil, name: 'martin'}]``` whereas Person.all.as_json(only: [:name]) returns ```[{name: 'joe'}, {name: 'martin'}]``` so for the more general case where you do not want the id, the the second method is better.

Comment: @Obromios I totally agree with you and would suggest the same. But if id is required then `Person.select(:id,:name).as_json` would be much cleaner.

Comment: The response by pascal betz is far more efficient than this one. This one basically creates N Person objects after the SQL query result and the iterates them to return the JSON. The pluck+map version iterates through the query result and creates the hash objects. A simple benchmark can verify this, in my machine results for 1000 tests return 395.65 seconds for the as_json version (all the runs) and just 26.63 seconds for the pluck+map version (all the runs), my database had 2.2k rows

Comment: `pluck` is quite a special method. It bypasses the key aspect of Rails that gives it a bad reputation for performance (and good reputation for expressivity). Crucially `select` doesn't satisfy this property. If you're going to dispense Rails' OOP benefits without grabbing the performance benefit is like forgetting to take something in a shop.

Comment: This approach is what got me googling for a better way. I was using this approach, but the performance was killing my app.  I switched to pluck+map and the result was staggering.

Comment: `as_json` is not a solution here as it defeats the purpose of calling `pluck`

Comment: I didn't need the json part to shove all this into a dropdown as a collection, just used `select` over `pluck` and it kept the named properties which helped with that mapping!

Comment: `.all` instantiates all the records before converting to json.

Comment: I'm getting 3 columns from a table. 

Person.pluck(:id, :first_name, :last_name)
But I wanna put it in a map, where id as key and name as value. where name is first_name + " " + last_name. How to do this in ruby the elegant way?

Comment: Also, it returns the hash `keys` as `strings` instead of `symbols`

Answer (score 53):

You can `map` the result:

```
Person.all.pluck(:id, :name).map { |id, name| {id: id, name: name}}
```

As mentioned by @alebian:
This is more efficient than

```
Person.all.as_json(only: [:id, :name])
```

Reasons:

- `pluck` only returns the used columns (:id, :name) whereas the other solution returns all columns. Depending on the width of the table (number of columns) this makes quite a difference
- The pluck solution does not instantiate `Person` objects, does not need to assign attributes to the models and so on. Instead it just returns an array with one integer and one string.
- `as_json` again has more overhead than the simple `map` as it is a generic implementation to convert a model to a hash

Comment: It uses '.map' which means i have to change the pluck and map when making a change.

Comment: Yes, not that nice. The `select` solution by @Rohit Jangid seems better.

Comment: This version is the most efficient, it should be the one selected

Comment: @pascalbetz I wish you hadn't insulted your own answer because the first option you gave is way more performant than the accepted answer.

Comment: As mentioned by others, I'm not fond of having to repeat myself in `pluck` and `map`, but the enormous performance gains over `as_json(only:)` far out weigh the code complexity in my use cases.

Comment: Verified with Benchmark, using `pluck` w/ `map` is 10x faster than `select` w/ `as_json`...and only 1x uglier, use this one!

Answer (score 22):

I see three options:

**1)** `pluck` plus `map`:

```
Person.pluck(:id, :name).map { |p| { id: p[0], name: p[1] } }
```

**2)** `pluck` plus `map` plus `zip` and a variable to make it DRY-er:

```
attrs = %w(id name)
Person.pluck(*attrs).map { |p| attrs.zip(p).to_h }
```

**3)** or you might not use `pluck` at all, although this is much less performant:

```
Person.all.map { |p| p.slice(:id, :name) }
```

Comment: This is awesome! I never thought about combing it with `.map()`, `.zip()`, and `.to_h`! Thanks for sharing @spickermann

Comment: Note that `p` is a method in Ruby, using it as a parameter for the `map` broke for me. Just use another name, like `toto`.

Comment: @pierre_loic A local variable in Ruby would shadow a outer method with the same name. That is default Ruby behavior. In this example Ruby would never confuse the variable p with the method p. You must have done something different than if you had such a problem.

Answer (score 11):

If you use postgresql, you can use `json_build_object` function in pluck method:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

That way, you can let db create hashes.

```
Person.pluck("json_build_object('id', id, 'name', name)")
#=> [{id: 1, name: 'joe'}, {id: 2, name: 'martin'}]
```

Comment: While this approach works, be aware that it is dangerous to use it. This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes. Known-safe values can be passed by wrapping them in Arel.sql()

Answer (score 7):

Could go for a hash after the pluck with the ID being the key and the Name being the value:

```
Person.all.pluck(:id, :name).to_h

{ 1 => 'joe', 2 => 'martin' }
```

Not sure if this fits your needs, but presenting as an option.

Comment: The ideia was to make a hash with the field name as the key

Comment: I understand. Just all depends on what you're doing with it. Sometimes you alter the data to fit the execution, and other times you alter the execution to fit the data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the aptly-named pluck_to_hash gem for this:
https://github.com/girishso/pluck_to_hash

It will extend AR with pluck_to_hash method that works like this:

```
Post.limit(2).pluck_to_hash(:id, :title)
#
# [{:id=>213, :title=>"foo"}, {:id=>214, :title=>"bar"}]
#

Post.limit(2).pluck_to_hash(:id)
#
# [{:id=>213}, {:id=>214}]
```

It claims to be several times faster than using AR `select` and `as_json`

Answer (score 3):

There is [pluck_all](https://github.com/khiav223577/pluck_all) gem that do almost the same thing as [pluck_to_hash](https://github.com/girishso/pluck_to_hash) do. And it claims that it's 30% faster. (see the benchmark [here](https://github.com/khiav223577/pluck_all#compare-with-pluck_to_hash-gem)).

**Usage:**

```
Person.pluck_all(:id, :name)
```

Comment: Most useful answer I'd say considering `pluck` is often used for performance and this is more performant than any of the other answers here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple attributes, you may do this for cleanliness:

```
Item.pluck(:id, :name, :description, :cost, :images).map do |item|
  {
    id:          item[0],
    name:        item[1],
    description: item[2],
    cost:        item[3],
    images:      item[4]
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks, This really helped my situation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the `pluck` method combined with the `zip` method.

```rb
attrs_array = %w(id name)
Person.all.pluck(attrs_array).map { |ele| attrs_array.zip(ele).to_h }
```

You can also create a helper method if you are using this method through out your application.

```rb
def pluck_to_hash(object, *attrs)
  object.pluck(*attrs).map { |ele| attrs.zip(ele).to_h }
end
```

Consider modifying by declaring `self` as the default receiver rather than passing `Person.all` as the `object` variable.

Read more about [zip](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip).

Comment: I'm getting 3 columns from a table. 

Person.pluck(:id, :first_name, :last_name)
But I wanna put it in a map, where id as key and name as value. where name is first_name + " " + last_name. How to do this in ruby the elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that has worked well for me:

```
    def pluck_to_hash(enumerable, *field_names)
      enumerable.pluck(*field_names).map do |field_values|
        field_names.zip(field_values).each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), result_hash|
          result_hash[key] = value
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread but in case someone is looking for simpler version of this

```rb
Hash[Person.all(:id, :name)]
```

Tested in Rails 5.